# Get highest column from worksheet phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Hi I need to import data from excel. I'm using phpexcel library. When I'm trying to get the highest column using

```
$worksheet->getHighestColumn();
```

I always got AMK.But the actual value is O. Im trying with another method

```
getHighestDataColumn()
```

Unfortunately this will return 1. What is the solution? Im new to phpexcel

```
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
                $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
                $highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
                $highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();
                $highestColumnIndex = \PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
                $nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;
}
```

Comment: That's because something in your worksheet i referencing a cell in column `AMK`.... consider using `getHighestDataColumn()` instead

Comment: getHighestDataColumn() returns 1

Comment: `getHighestDataColumn()` should never, ever return `1`. It should ___always___ return a letter or letter sequence